# duda sobre ámbito en c++

Tags: c++

Practicando sobre pilas en el ejercicio se me pidió multiplicar una pila a n numero definido por el usuario :

###### objetivo

Dentro del ámbito de mi función menú definí una condicional  para que cuando el usuario rellene la pila esta condicional detecte si esta o no vacía y mostrar un mensaje:

###### problema

Al declarar mi puntero pila dentro del ámbito de mi función menú, al llenar la pila la condicional no fue capaz de detectar si mi pila esta o no vacía lo que hice fue declarar al puntero pila de manera global y si funcionó.

###### duda

¿Por qué al declararla mi puntero pila dentro del ámbito de mi función menú no funciono en cambio al declararlo de manera global si funcionó? ¿Cómo funciona el ámbito en este caso?

edito : aquí  esta el código completo para entender mejor mi pregunta

**código con el problema**

```
//multiplicar todos los numeros de una pila 

#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

struct num
{
    int d;
    num *sig;
};
void menu();
void mult(num *pila,int m);
void ingpl(num *&pila,int d);
void sacpl(num *&pila,int &d);


int main()
{
    menu(); 
    return 0;   
}


void sacpl(num *&pila,int &d)
{
    num *aux = pila;
    d = aux->d;
    pila = aux->sig;
    delete aux;
}

void ingpl(num *&pila,int d)
{
    num *n_nodo = new num();
    n_nodo->d = d;
    n_nodo->sig = pila;
    pila = n_nodo;
    std::cout<<d<<" se agrego a pila ";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}

void mult(num *p,int m)
{
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<m<<" por "<<p->d<<" : "<<(p->d) * m<<'\n';
        p = p->sig;
    }
    std::cin.ignore().get();
}

void menu()
{
    num *pila = NULL; //al haber declarado mi puntero pila dentro del ambito de la funcion menu la condicional no fue capaz de detectar si estaba o no vacia mi pila
    int data,rsp,opc;
    system("cls");
    if(pila != NULL) std::cout<<"la pila se encuentra con datos "<<'\n';
    else std::cout<<"la pila esta vacia "<<'\n';
    std::cout<<R"(
    
        menu 
        
    1) llenar la pila
    2) multiplicar a n numero la pila
    3) eliminar pila y salir del programa
    
    >> )";
    std::cin>>opc;
    switch(opc)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            while(true)
            {   
                system("cls");
                std::cout<<"elemento : ";
                fflush(stdin);
                std::cin>>data;
                    
                ingpl(pila,data);
                std::cout<<"\nseguir agregando ? (1/0) : ";
                std::cin>>rsp;
                if(rsp>=1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            menu();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            int m;
            std::cout<<"numero sobre el cual multiplicar la pila : ";
            std::cin>>m;
            mult(pila,m);
            menu();
            break;
        case 3:
            {
                std::cout<<"eliminando pila : ";
                while(pila != NULL)
                {
                    sacpl(pila,data);
                    if(pila != NULL)
                    {
                        std::cout<<data<<" , ";
                    }
                    else{
                        std::cout<<data<<" . ";
                    }
                }
            break;
            }
        default:
            std::cout<<"opcion incorrecta recargando ... "<<'\n';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            menu();
            break;
    }
    
}
```

**código arreglado después del problema**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>

struct num
{
    int d;
    num *sig;
};
void menu();
void mult(num *pila,int m);
void ingpl(num *&pila,int d);
void sacpl(num *&pila,int &d);

num *pila = NULL;


int main()
{
    menu(); 
    return 0;   
}


void sacpl(num *&pila,int &d)
{
    num *aux = pila;
    d = aux->d;
    pila = aux->sig;
    delete aux;
}

void ingpl(num *&pila,int d)
{
    num *n_nodo = new num();
    n_nodo->d = d;
    n_nodo->sig = pila;
    pila = n_nodo;
    std::cout<<d<<" se agrego a pila ";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}

void mult(num *p,int m)
{
    while(p != NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<m<<" por "<<p->d<<" : "<<(p->d) * m<<'\n';
        p = p->sig;
    }
    std::cin.ignore().get();
}

void menu()
{
    
    int data,rsp,opc;
    system("cls");
    if(pila != NULL) std::cout<<"la pila se encuentra con datos "<<'\n';
    else std::cout<<"la pila esta vacia "<<'\n';
    std::cout<<R"(
    
        menu 
        
    1) llenar la pila
    2) multiplicar a n numero la pila
    3) eliminar pila y salir del programa
    
    >> )";
    std::cin>>opc;
    switch(opc)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            while(true)
            {   
                system("cls");
                std::cout<<"elemento : ";
                fflush(stdin);
                std::cin>>data;
                    
                ingpl(pila,data);
                std::cout<<"\nseguir agregando ? (1/0) : ";
                std::cin>>rsp;
                if(rsp>=1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            menu();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            int m;
            std::cout<<"numero sobre el cual multiplicar la pila : ";
            std::cin>>m;
            mult(pila,m);
            menu();
            break;
        case 3:
            {
                std::cout<<"eliminando pila : ";
                while(pila != NULL)
                {
                    sacpl(pila,data);
                    if(pila != NULL)
                    {
                        std::cout<<data<<" , ";
                    }
                    else{
                        std::cout<<data<<" . ";
                    }
                }
            break;
            }
        default:
            std::cout<<"opcion incorrecta recargando ... "<<'\n';
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
            menu();
            break;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Las variables globales se inicializan a cero (nulo en caso de punteros) mientras que las locales no. Pero no puedo saber si es tu caso sin ver las declaraciones y los usos.

Comment: Si tienes dudas del ámbito de una variable en función de dónde la definas, deberías publicar en tu pregunta las definiciones y los ámbitos en las que los usas. Y aquí no hay ninguna de las dos cosas.

Comment: listo ya edite la pregunta lamento no haberla formulado correctamente

Comment: Has puesto en tu pregunta una sección titulada "*código arreglado después del problema*" ¿Se ha solucionado tu problema?

Comment: una disculpa para todos ustedes soy bastante novato aquí y no me supe expresar muy bien en mi pregunta  mi objetivo no era que arreglaran mi código si no que me explicaran como funciona el ámbito  en c++  en este caso de manera global y local  era un tema que me confundía bastante pero ya lo he comprendido y pues aporto con mi respuesta para todo aquel que le pueda servir

Comment: gracias por la atención a todos ustedes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en base a lo aprendido solucionando mi problema

**¿como funciona el ámbito?**

A partir de un identificador introducido en el código mediante una declaración este sera conocido por el compilador en una región o zona denominada ámbito , es decir si se realiza un cambio en el identificador solo se aplicaría dentro de este ámbito mas no de manera global en el código :

en mi código dentro del ámbito de mi función menú inicialice mi puntero pila a NULL

esta declaración no es valida para el resto del código debido a que se intenta acceder a mi pila principal que no se encuentra dentro del **ámbito** o "región" de mi función menu

```
...
//!!pila principal fuera de ámbito de mi función menú ¡¡

struct num
{
    int d;
    num *sig;
};

...

void menu ()
{   //dentro de ámbito de mi función menú 

    num *pila = NULL; //declaración no valida pila principal no esta en el ámbito de mi función menú
    int data,rsp,opc;
    system("cls");
    if(pila != NULL) std::cout<<"la pila se encuentra con datos "<<'\n'; 
    else std::cout<<"la pila esta vacia "<<'\n'; 
    
    ...

}
```

solo en algunas regiones de su ámbito el identificador sera visible,
es decir lo podemos usar para designar  a la misma entidad sin necesidad de un cualificado

**ejemplo**

```
#include<iostream>

int x = 10;

int main()
{
    for(int x=0;x<3;x++) //variable x principal no visible en la region (ambito) de mi bucle for
    {
        //variable de mi bucle for solo visible dentro del ambito de este
        
        std::cout<<x<<'\n'; 
    }
    
    std::cout<<x<<'\n'; 
}
```

en la practica este deja de ser visible dentro del ámbito
si este es eclipsado por otra declaración explicita que use el mismo nombre.

**ejemplo**

```
#include<iostream>

int x = 20;


int main()
{
    int x = 10; //variable x principal ecplipsada por la declaracion explicita a x local
    std::cout<<x<<'\n'; 
    
    
}
```

el conjunto de estas regiones es su área de **visibilidad** (scope)

fuera de este ámbito como en este caso mi puntero pila y el ámbito mi función menú,mi puntero pila no sera valido
o no visible para el resto de funciones

ámbito y scope se refieren a una zona del código (bloque o agrupación de sentencias),
mientras que la visibilidad es una propiedad puntual que puede cambiar en cada linea del **ámbito**

**ejemplo**

```
#include<iostream>

int x;

int main()
{ 
    x = 20; //!!genial¡¡ x esta visible o "scope"
    
    int x = 30; //nueva declaracion de x  ( dos variables x visibles)
    
    std::cout<<x<<'\n'; //ok acceso a variable  x local dentro del ambito de mi funcion 
    std::cout<<::x; //ok acceso a viariable x global  mediante el nombre cualificado
    
    
    std::cout<<"    "<<'\n';
    for(int j=0;j<1;j++)
    { 
        int x = 0; //tercera variable x su visibilidad solo esta disponible en el ambito del bucle
        std::cout<<x<<'\n';
    }   
    std::cout<<x<<'\n';
    std::cout<<::x<<'\n';  
    //variable x local del bucle for NO visible o fuera del ámbito del mismo
    
}
```

**solución**

remover a mi puntero pila del ámbito de mi función menú

y declararlo e inicializarlo de manera global en mi código para que sea **visible**

para todas las funciones de mi código :

```
...

struct num
{
    int d;
    num *sig;

};

void menu();
void mult(num *pila,int m);
void ingpl(num *&pila,int d);
void sacpl(num *&pila,int &d);


num *pila = NULL; //ok declaración correcta y visible para todas las funciones

...
```